# Using Numpy to find combination of rows in an array such that each column sums to the same value

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, data-science

I'm trying to use `numpy` to find configurations of rows in a matrix such that summing the columns of the rows will result in the same value. As an example, for the matrix/array

```
[[0,0,0,1],
 [1,0,1,0],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0]]
```

I would like to have the first, second, and last row as output, because

```
  0,0,0,1
  1,0,1,0
  0,1,0,0 +
  -------
= 1,1,1,1
```

Is there any tools built into `numpy` that would assist me in acquiring this?

Comment: Do you want all the combinations consisting of any number of rows that matches your criteria? If so, this problem seems computationally rather hard to me at first glance.

Comment: `numpy` makes testing row combinations easy, `arr[idx,:].sum(axis=0)`.  But `numpy` doesn't provide search tools - whether brute force or smart.

Comment: Are your array entries integer?

Comment: yep, they're all integers - either 0 or 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to enumerate the power set of rows and then check each possible subset of rows for the summation condition. For matrices with a large number of rows, this is likely to be quite slow.

Use the standard itertools recipe for the power set:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    xs = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(xs, n) for n in range(len(xs) + 1))
```

then I show a working example with some synthetic data:

```
In [79]: data
Out[79]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [80]: def is_constant(array):
    ...:     return (array == array[0]).all()
    ...: 

In [81]: solution = []

In [82]: for candidate in powerset(range(len(data))):
    ...:     if candidate and is_constant(data[candidate, :].sum(axis=0)):
    ...:         solution.append(candidate)
    ...:
```

Which shows, for example:

```
In [83]: solution
Out[83]: 
[(4,),
 (6,),
 (8,),
 (1, 7),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 9),
 (4, 6),
 (4, 8),
 (6, 8),
 (0, 2, 7),
 (1, 4, 7),
 (1, 6, 7),
 (1, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 7),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (2, 4, 9),
 (2, 5, 6),
 (2, 5, 8),
 (2, 6, 9),
 (2, 8, 9),
 (4, 6, 8),
 (0, 2, 4, 7),
 (0, 2, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 7, 9),
 (1, 4, 6, 7),
 (1, 4, 7, 8),
 (1, 6, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 4, 7),
 (2, 3, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 7, 8),
 (2, 4, 5, 6),
 (2, 4, 5, 8),
 (2, 4, 6, 9),
 (2, 4, 8, 9),
 (2, 5, 6, 8),
 (2, 6, 8, 9),
 (0, 2, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 4, 7, 8),
 (0, 2, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 7, 9),
 (1, 2, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 5, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 6, 7, 9),
 (1, 2, 7, 8, 9),
 (1, 4, 6, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 4, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 6, 7, 8),
 (2, 4, 5, 6, 8),
 (2, 4, 6, 8, 9),
 (0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9),
 (1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9),
 (1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

and we can verify the solution for a few of these cases:

```
In [84]: data[(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9), :].sum(axis=0)
Out[84]: array([4, 4, 4])

In [85]: data[(0, 2, 4, 6, 7), :].sum(axis=0)
Out[85]: array([3, 3, 3])
```

To extend this for more specific use cases, you could use `itertools.combinations` to produce subsets of only a certain size, like subsets of exactly 2 rows or exactly 3 rows, etc.

Or you could just filter out unwanted results (like trivial solutions consisting of one row at a time) from the result set given in my example.

Note you can simplify the function definition of `powerset` (the one I use is literally just taken from the Python docs about itertools recipes). Instead of passing an iterable that gets converted to a list, you could just pass an integer and skip directly to return the final `chain.from_iterable` result, and then modify to just pass `len(data)` as the argument of `powerset` in my example, like this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(N):
    """Power set of integers {0, ..., N-1}."""
    xs = list(range(N))
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(xs, n) for n in range(N + 1))

...
for candidate in powerset(len(data)):
    ...
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! However you were quite accurate in it being computationally very slow for big matrices. Regardless, you answered the question excellently - thank you very much!